# How to open edge and login to microsoft account with Python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, microsoft-edge

I'd put in my microsoft account, and it would open microsoft edge sign into microsoft.

I am using python and selenium.

If anyone could help it would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Ive tried this:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Edge()

driver.get('i dont have a link ')

---

As you can see there is no link for the sign in and sync. Would i have to find the button element?

https://ibb.co/xjsn6jM

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, please include what you have tried so far, and more specifics of your project.

Comment: You could first follow the steps mentioned in [Use WebDriver to automate Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=python#automate-microsoft-edge), then replace the link you want to access, and test it. If you encounter any problems during the process, please provide more detailed information.

Comment: @RainaZhao-MSFT that wouldnt work because when theres no link to the sign in and sync its a popup

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, you want to sign in Edge with a specific profile automatically.

You could try the sample code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
 
driver = webdriver.Edge()
 
edge_options = Options()
edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data")
edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default");

driver.get('https://bing.com')
time.sleep(5000)
```

Also, you need to check your profile path by going to "**edge://version**" in the address bar.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! and how would i add the credentials?

Comment: You need to sign into Microsoft Edge manually. Please refer to [Sign in and create multiple profiles in Microsoft Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/sign-in-and-create-multiple-profiles-in-microsoft-edge-df94e622-2061-49ae-ad1d-6f0e43ce6435#:~:text=1%20Create%20multiple%20profiles.%202%20Select%20Profile%2C%20then,The%20additional%20profiles%20are%20now%20available%20for%20selection.). And then follow the steps above, launch the Edge with a specific profile automatically. Otherwise, Selenium creates a new profile every time you launch the Edge browser.

Comment: Hi @bilo , May I know if the answer above is helpful for you? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: @ Raina Zhao-MSFT i dont know how to find the elemnt to click on, i dont think there is a link to actualy interact with because when you try to create a profile in edge there is a popup that doesnt have any elemnts that selenium can use